# type error showing in angular algolia instantSearch

Tags: angular, algolia

while I use angular navigation to the component it navigates immediately return to the previous page and showing this error in the console log

```
core.js:14597 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'addAlgoliaAgent' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addAlgoliaAgent' of undefined
    at NgAisInstantSearch.push../node_modules/angular-instantsearch/fesm5/angular-instantsearch.js.NgAisInstantSearch.createInstantSearchInstance (angular-instantsearch.js:223)
    at NgAisInstantSearch.push../node_modules/angular-instantsearch/fesm5/angular-instantsearch.js.NgAisInstantSearch.ngOnInit (angular-instantsearch.js:179)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:20665)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:21929)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:21891)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:22525)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:22485)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (CollegeComponent.html:6)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:22477)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21873)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:16147)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be related with the beta version, and consequently the problem is corrected by using the latest version 2.2.2 
I just had the same problem. I was using the beta version (3.0.0-beta.4
) of angular-instantsearch. 
I replaced it with the latest version (2.2.2) and the problem was corrected.